# Passing ID in codeigniter form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

How can I pass a row ID in codeigniter form? I have this Code

```
if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
    <?php echo form_open('site/update/'); ?>
    <td><?php echo form_input('solution_time', $row->solution_time); ?></td>
    <td><textarea><?php echo $row->note; ?></textarea></td>
    <td><?php echo form_submit('update', 'Update'); ?></td>
    <?php form_close(); ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>No Records</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But it returns 1 for every row's ID like that every time:

```
localhost/it/index.php/site/update/1
```

Update: I have added a new line (form_hidden) and it's not working too

```
if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
        <?php echo form_open('site/update/'); ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('id', $row->id); ?>
        <td><?php echo form_input('solution_time', $row->solution_time); ?></td>
        <td><textarea><?php echo $row->note; ?></textarea></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('update', 'Update'); ?></td>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h2>No Records</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: did you try $row['id'] as well?

Comment: Do `var_dump($row);` and show what it looks like.

Comment: object(stdClass)#17 (7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["time"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["department"]=> string(10) "department" ["problem"]=> string(5) "Issue" ["solution_time"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["note"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @ari4x That's what `var_dump($row);` gives back, and of course all the other rows too.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the row id to the form open. What you're doing is creating a bunch of forms with the same action and the submit is only passing the first one back to the controller. Passing the ID in the form action should fix that.

```
 <?php echo form_open('site/update/'.$row->id); ?>
```

The other option is to use jQuery to do the updates.

```
        $(document).on("click", ".updateLink", function() {
    $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>site/update/",
        data: $row.find('input').serialize(),
  dataType: "json",
        success: function(content) {
            if (content.status == "success") {
                $row.stop().css("background-color", "#99FF66").animate({backgroundColor: "#FFF"}, 1500);
            } else {

            $("#error").html('<p>'+content.message+'</p>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In your form change the submit buttons to links:

```
<td><?php echo <a href="#" class="updateLink">Update</a></td>
```

Then in your controller you just have to echo back a success message on success.

```
if(update successfull)
{
    print json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>""));
}
```

Comment: Actually it was like that first, I have updated the question now take a look

Comment: When I first looked you weren't passing the id in the form action, you still aren't. View the source on your page, I guarantee you have a bunch of forms all with exactly the same action and a bunch of submit buttons with exactly the same name. It's going to grab the first id it comes across in that case.

Comment: See answer edit, added a jquery solution that works fine for me when doing multiples on one page, the upside is you never leave the page so you can update as many as you want.

Comment: It's not working it gives back this link `/index.php/it/check#`

Comment: Did you add jquery to the page? You need to reference it in the head. http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-always-reference-latest-version.html

Comment: Yes, but this `href="#"` should be like this or I have to change it?

Comment: It's irrelevant, that is just pointing to an anchor, you can just leave the href blank but I personally always just drop an anchor in there. If the jquery is being executed properly it won't transfer to the address bar. You can check the results in Chrome in the inspector. Hit F12, change to Network, click on XHR at the bottom and you can see what is being sent and the response there when you click your links, will help you trouble shoot the ajax call if it isn't working

Comment: Thanks a lot, This XHR helped me I had problem with my `base_url`

Comment: Sorry @Rick Calder but it's not working i thought it work but it's not updating the page

Comment: What do you mean not updating the page? The ajax call works, trust me but if something fails in the update code in the controller or model it won't do anything, that's why I said check the XHR. If the request works it will be black text, if it doesn't red. You should be able to see any errors returned via the response tab.